# Spring Security and Post Task after getting token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Security and have a project using a modified version of it. I rely on the default Spring '/oauth/token' endpoint where doing a HTTP POST with proper info (client-id, etc) will return access_token and info with 200 OK Response.

Because this is implemented by Spring I don't have access to modify, but I would like to set up a post-task based on response code. If someone successfully hit the '/oauth/token' endpoint with proper information, I want to do something. I am not sure what to override and what to do in setting up a listener on when should this 'posttask' occur

Answer (score 0):

Add your own custom Authentication Provider, which should be called after `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

For example add below lines into your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extended class:

```
@Autowired
UserStateAuthenticationProvider userStateAuthenticationProvider;



@Autowired
 public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
 Exception {
     auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
     auth.authenticationProvider(userStateAuthenticationProvider);
 }
```

where `UserStateAuthenticationProvider` can be your own custom class

like

```
public class UserStateAuthenticationProvider{

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
      throws AuthenticationException {

        //....do anything you want like below
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(
          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```